# Google Apps Script triggers E-mail Notification

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

First off, I'd like to apologize if this has already been answered. I certainly hope not.

Anyways, here's the idea of what I'm doing.

Using Google Drive, a user is supposed to be able to fill out a form and submit it.
On the submission of the form, a script is triggered.
The script is supposed to send an e-mail to an account within our domain in order to notify them that a new form has been submitted.

Here's the script I'm using to do that:

```
function emailnotifacs1() {
var recipient = "user@domain.net";
var subject = "New Form Is In!";
var body = "Check the spreadsheet." +
" Link: spreadsheetLink.com";
MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);

}
```

For some reason, each time I attempt to debug the script, it asks that I re-authorize the script, Literally *every time*.

And each time the script is automatically ran (on Submit), it doesn't run at all and gives me this e-mail:
`You do not have permission to call openById`
It's triggering on `formEdit`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and returned with free internet cookies.

Thanks,
Alex Lee

Answer (score 0):

You might try to trigger emailnotifacs1() with "On form submit" instead
and maybe share more code if that doesn't fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

According to [this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3832), to fix it, you have to pre-authorize the function that will be run. To do that, you can just go into your script editor and run the function.

However, if your function is meant to be run on a trigger, you won't be able to run your function straight from the script editor (e.g. my function is only supposed to be run onSubmit and it does things to the form that's been submitted, so if I run it from the script editor I'll get errors because the form doesn't exist).

So I wrapped the code in my triggered function in a try-catch loop, ran it from the script editor menu, and voila, my code started working.

Also, in your case, you may want to check that the trigger is properly set up to call `emailnotifacs1` on form submit. And `emailnotifacs1` should be accepting an `event` parameter - see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events) for more info.

NOTE: Every time you make changes to the function, you'll need to re-authorize it by running it from the script editor!